# How to escape square bracket, curly bracket for "contains text" query in xQuery (BaseX)?

Tags: escaping, xquery, basex

I'm working with a BaseX in which we integrate TEI files.

We are looking for results that contain items with the following text:

> "{AAXX}".

The braces are part of the text. (Note that sometimes there are also brackets or chevrons, we have same problems).

I have tried several types of queries to find the text in braces (with braces), but nothing works.

Below is a piece of the query:

```
/p[. contains text {"{AAXXXX}"} all words using case insensitive using wildcards  ]
```

How to escape braces, square brackets or chevrons? I tried to encode the braces in several ways, to double them, to escape them with a backslash but nothing helps, the results don't take the braces into account (just to mention this case)

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

It can't be done.
The `contains text` syntax is part of [XQuery and XPath Full Text](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-full-text-10/). This is concerned with searching for words and phrases and not symbols. The BaseX function `ft:tokenize` can be used to see how your search string is interpreted :

```
ft:tokenize("word 1.3 +, {AAXXXX}")
word
1
3
aaxxxx
```

The symbols are just ignored. You could use full text to search for the 'AAXXXX' and then additional XQuery code to look at the surrounding context.